# How to fetch image from temporary storage in Django

Tags: python, django, static, temporary-files

I am new at Django. I am uploading images in temporary storage using tempfile but i am now confused how to fetch that image and show on html side.

views.py

```
temp = tempfile.mkdtemp()
predictable_filename = 'myfile'
temporary_location = os.path.join(temp,predictable_filename)

def upload_multiple_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFaceImageForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['name'] = file_name
            request.session['image'] = request.FILES['image'].name
            with open(temporary_location + file_name, "w") as tmp:
                tmp.write(file_name)
                return redirect("show_image")
    else:
        return render(request, 'camera/upload_knowface_images.html')

def show_image(request):
    pass
```

How to fetch image in show_image function

Comment: Follow sole turorials : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-uploading-images-in-django/

Comment: https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-file-and-image-uploads-tutorial

Comment: Tnx for replay but how to fetch image path and name from temporary stoarge

Comment: you put in : temporary_location/file_name , get it from there:) Pls follow this tutorials ;)